# scroll websites with django

Tags: django, web, scroll

I'm currently working on a simple scroll website with nothing really difficult (I could almost use plain html/css/javascript but it's a bit of practicing and I will maybe add a blog). And as it is simple I was wondering how to do it properly with Django.

So here is my question, I have a homepage template that is actually the website and I don't really get how I split my different part in different apps.

For exemple I have a contact form, do I need to split it in another app and then include it in the basic template ? I want to add a galery with image in a database, do I create an app for that ?

And the other question that goes along is how do I code an app that is not returning httpresponse but just html to put it in another template and do I still need views ? I would like to do a bit like a standard form in django where you do :

form.as_p or form.as_table

so maybe:

galery.as_slideshow

So my questions are quite novice and open but someone could give me some reading to get going, I would be really happy !

Answer (score 0):

This is a question a lot of people struggle with and it seems like there are a lot of varying opinions out there.

I've found that the best way to really determine the appropriate answer for each case is to really distill the feature into individual requirements and group them by feature sets while keeping an eye out for additional uses outside of the project actively being worked on.

There is nothing which says you can't build your project to include a single app containing all of the modules you would need. Doing so seems like it would make your development easier initially right? So, the question to ask then is "What if I want to reuse (insert feature set here) in another unrelated project a year from now after I've already forgotten about the weird stuff I did to make it work originally?". Asking yourself that question forces you to think about your features in a much broader context and I think 99% of the time you will realize that a "Contact Form" requirement can actually become quite complex and really should be split up into at least one separate app (i.e. User Creation, Profile Management, Email Subscription, etc...)

Here is a link to a video about this very topic which I found to be useful in figuring out my way through this question:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-S0tqpPga4

I know this is not really a hard-line answer to your question but I hope it helps point you in the right direction.